# Vue-Router: How to disable the path's hash globally & add it in certain routes?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

There are an application, where routes handles by two sides: some routes handles by CMS, and some with vue-router. For example: `http://localhost/` handles by **CMS and webserver**, but http://localhost/complex-page/#/my-route handles by both: **CMS** and **Vue router**.

That means It has two `vue-router` instances: global (just for use `$route` globaly, it use a `history` mode) and local (for using with `hash` mode). And here is a problem: local router behaves as if he overrides global mode and and hash adds to route everywhere, even there is no components with local routings.

**Here is code that pretty close to real project:**

```js
let first = {
  name: "first",
  template: `<section><h1>First</h1></section>`
};


let second = {
  name: "second",
  template: `<section><h2>Second</h2></section>`
};

let outerComponent = Vue.component('container', {
  template: `
  <section>
    <h2>Outer</h2>
    <h3>Path: {{window.location.href}}</h3>
    <nav>
      <router-link to='/first' append>First</router-link>
      <router-link to='/second' append>Second</router-link>
    </nav> 
    <h3>Inner:</h3>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </section>
  `,
  router: new VueRouter({
    mode: 'hash', // HASH!!!
    components: {
      'first': first,
      'second': second
    },
    routes: [{
        path: "/first",
        component: first,
        name: "first"
      },
      {
        path: "/second",
        component: second,
        name: "second"
      }
    ]
  })
});


// Root!
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router: new VueRouter({
    mode: "history" // HISTORY!
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/3.1.3/vue-router.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <!-- Even if delete this node, hash will be added -->
  <container></container>
</div>
```

**How to disable the path's hash globally & add it in certain routes?**

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the **`#`** globally by adding **`mode: 'history',`** like so:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```

You can read more in the **[official documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-history-mode)**.

**EDIT:**

If you want the **`#`** on a certain routes, you could accomplish it like so:

```
const router =
        new VueRouter({
            mode: 'history',
            routes: [
                {
                    path: "#/my-component-1",
                    component: MyComponent_1
                },
                {
                    path: "#/my-component-2",
                    component: MyComponent_2
                }
            ]
        });

export default {
        components: {
            // ... my routed components here
        },
        router
    }
```

Comment: Where should I place that code? Index.js? I tried something like that, but it did't help

Comment: @YesMan which code the first or second code snippet?

Comment: @YesMan I have updated my answer. Check the code that I added it. I used the same code sample that you provided before with the `mode: 'history',` line added in it.

Comment: You talking about my local component? I don't understand, how local router can change global routes?

Comment: @YesMan let's tackle a problem at a time. By adding `mode: 'history',` you should get rid of the hash symbol in the url, can you confirm that it works?

Comment: Yes, it works, but it is not all I want to get done. I need to get a hash in certain components. I tried to add you second code snippet, but it is not worked for me. What your "pathName" variable contains?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201427/discussion-between-manuel-abascal-and-yes-man).

Answer (score 1):

Just remove # enable history mode

```
new VueRoute({
    //...
    mode:'history'
   //....
})
```